# Imported Excel Spreadsheet Creates Null Values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel, arcgis-10.5

I've imported an Excel spreadsheet into ArcMap 10.5 and one of the columns entirely populates with NULL values. That column is just "reference numbers" so its just numbers from 1-180 in increasing value.

Does anyone know why this is happening and a possible workaround?

Comment: In Excel, select the number from 1 - 180, go to Cell Properties and choose `Number` instead of `General` and click `OK`. Then import the excel file again into ArcMap. Sometimes ArcMap does not like `General` format of the cell and need to explicitly format the column as `Number`

Comment: I tried that, still doesnt work :/

Comment: What is the name of the column that contains the data?

Comment: Just to keep it simple I just made it Ref

Comment: After you made it Ref, is it still not working?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Is the _first_ row your header (so ref in your case) and the _second_ row number 1? If you have hidden rows/columns that messes things up.

Comment: It is, I have not hidden anything

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possible workarounds:

**1) Populate the field with incrementing values again using Field Calculator.**
If you really need those values in ArcMap, go to field calculator and enter the following code block (taken from the [ArcGIS Calculate Field Examples](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004s000000)), making sure you specify Python as the parser:

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
    global rec
    pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd
    pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
    if (rec == 0):
        rec = pStart
    else:
        rec = rec + pInterval
    return rec
```

In the expression you should write: `autoIncrement()`

**2) Delete the Ref column from the spreadsheet.** If the resulting table in ArcMap contains a FID field, you would not need the Ref column as it contains the exact same values.

Comment: I will try the first option, but also worth noting when I import the spreadsheet, a FID field doesnt show up